# a C Program to create two variables with 10 and 20 and print their sum using pointer

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int sum(int*a,int*b)
{
    int s=0;
    s=*a=*b;
    return s ;
}

int main()
{
    int num1=10 , num2=20 ,*ptr1 ,*ptr2 ,sum=0 ;
    ptr1=&num1;
    ptr2=&num2;
    sum = sum(*ptr1,*ptr2);
    printf("sum of two variables is %d",sum);
    return 0;


}
```

//it is showing "main.c:18:8: error: called object ‘sum’ is not a function or function pointer"
//how to solve this error

Comment: Just change the name of the function.

Comment: `s=*a=*b;` -> `s=*a+*b;`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the same name for a local variable and a function.  You called them both `sum`.  The compiler is getting confused about which one you want.  Change the name of one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You get The Error because you cant use the name "sum" twice.

Further your code contains a two more problems:

- you can't just declare a pointer without a type, since they are of different length depending what they are referencing.
- your function expects a pointer not an address, but you are giving it the value of the pointer.

BTW you could solve the problem without declaring so much extra stuff, even if you want to work with an extra function and pass along pointers :)